# When i install stable diffusion on my pc i get error 128, about repositories and folders in them, how do i solve this problem (python 3.10.6)

Tags: python, git, stable-diffusion

I have the following error:

```bash
Error code: 128
stdout: <empty>
stderr: fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'D:28_Stable_Diffusion/stble/s/repositories/stable-diffusion-stability-ai'
'D:28_Stable_Diffusion/stble/s/repositories/stable-diffusion-stability-ai' is on a file system that does not record ownership
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory D:28_Stable_Diffusion/stble/s/repositories/stable-diffusion-stability-ai
```

I have tried deleting repositories as described in the git forum.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option to make that message disappear is to edit your global config and fix the path:

```
git config --global --edit
# fix path with D:\28_Stable_Diffusion\stble\s\repositories/stable-diffusion-stability-a
```

A Git config can handle Windows paths with `\` in them.
Double-check the '`stble`' part (for a possible typo: '`stable`').

If the path was not yet recorded, then you can proceed with:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory D:\28_Stable_Diffusion\stble\s\repositories/stable-diffusion-stability-a
```